# Putting a conditional action within a statement

Tags: java, operators

I have this code here:

```
public int withoutDoubles(int die1, int die2, boolean noDoubles) {
  if (noDoubles && die1 == die2) return ((die1 + 1) % 6 + die2);
  else return die1 + die2;
}
```

I would like to get it so that if it's at a 6 when the modulus operator is run through, it puts a 6 instead of a 0. I know that I could do it with an additional `if` statement, but I'd prefer to keep it as it is, with only one `if-else` pair. Is this possible?

Comment: No. That is not possible. The remainder is `0`. It will not be `6`. It cannot be `6`. That is math.

Comment: I'm saying to add a thing that checks if the remainder is `0` and and adds `6` if it is

Comment: You could use ternary operator instead of nested if

Comment: `(die1 % 6) + 1`

Comment: Thank you @rgettman, as that did in fact solve my issue! I don't know why I even put it inside in the first place!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promoting a comment to an answer.

The modulus operator `%` will yield a range between 0 and 5.  It will leave 1-5 alone and change 6 to 0.  Add one *after* the modulus operation to translate the range back to 1-6.

```
(die1 % 6) + 1
```